# How to mock store with initial state of feature module in parent app module

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular8, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-test

I'm using angular 8. I have a module `app` and a sub-module 'feature'. Both have their own stores. 'app.module.ts' has

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({ 'app': reducer }),
    ...
}]
```

Same way, 'feature' module has

```
StoreModule.forFeature('feature', fromFeature.reducer)
```

Now, while testing an `app` level component in jasmine, I mock the Store as follow

```
let store: MockStore<State>;
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports: [
   StoreModule.forRoot({'app' : reducer})
 ],
 providers: [
   provideMockStore({initialState})
 ]
```

where `initialState` is initial state for `app` module. However, while trying to get `store = TestBed.get(Store);`I get error for undefined values for `state` of `feature` module, where it tries to access the selectors from `feature` module.

What I understand is, I need to initialize the mockStore with state of whole app, not just `app` module state. However, I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I did try to import `StoreModule.forFeature('feature', featureReducer)` and initialize mockstore as `provideMockStore({initialState:: {initialState, featureInitialState}})`, but i still get feature state `undefined` for the selectors.

Error looks like the following

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEntity' of undefined
at getIsEntity (VM17 main.js:50252)
at store.js:583
at memoized (store.js:525)
at defaultStateFn (store.js:552)
at store.js:586
at memoized (store.js:525)
at MapSubscriber.project (store.js:480)
```

where `getIsEntity` is a `feature` module selector define as follow:

```
const getIsEntity = (state: State): boolean => state.isEntity
```

How can i mock/pass initial state for the feature module in parent app module?

Answer (score 0):

Mock it as the root store, because there are not own stores, all reducers / actions and effects always work with the store (a single root store), whereas calling "forFeature" makes an impression that they have own stores.

No they do not, they access the same root store.

```js
let store: MockStore<State>;
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports: [
   StoreModule.forRoot({
     'app' : reducer,
     'feature': ....,
   })
 ],
 providers: [
   provideMockStore({initialState})
 ]
```

Unfortunately, because of a low amount of information it is hard to point to the exact error place, but below you can check a working example:

```js
describe('suite', () => {
    let fixture: MockedComponentFixture<TestedComponent>;
    let storeState: DeepPartial<StoreState & {ngrxCorrelationId: {tasks: Array<string>; payloads: unknown}}>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const actions = new Observable<{}>();
        storeState = {
            ngrxCorrelationId: {
                tasks: [],
                payloads: {},
            },
            v2ProjectEntity: {
                ids: [],
                entities: {},
                lists: {},
            },
            v2PermissionsEntity: {},
        };

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestedComponent],
            providers: [
                provideMockStore({
                    initialState: storeState,
                }),
                provideMockActions(() => actions),
                {
                    provide: LoaderService,
                    useValue: createSpyObj('LoaderService', ['setLoaderStatus', 'hideLoader']),
                },
                {
                    provide: Router,
                    useValue: createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate', 'navigateByUrl']),
                },
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue: {
                        queryParams: new Subject(),
                    },
                },
                TestedEffects,
            ],
        });
        fixture = MockRender(TestedComponent);
    });

    it('listens on initial load public projects of the smart component', inject(
        [ActivatedRoute, Store],
        (activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, store: Store<{}>) => {
            const props = {
                cid: 'public',
                options: {
                    relations: [
                        'location',
                        'location.address',
                        'quotations',
                        'quotations.owner',
                        'quotations.owner.company',
                        'quotations.documents',
                        'certificates',
                        'certificatesCustom',
                        'documents',
                    ],
                    scopes: ['public'],
                    filters: {
                        category: undefined,
                        deadline: undefined,
                    },
                    order: undefined,
                },
            };
            spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
            (<Subject<{}>>activatedRoute.queryParams).next({});
            fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(publicProjectsListLoad({...props}));
        },
    ));

    it('listens on load public projects with filters of the smart component', inject(
        [ActivatedRoute, Store],
        (activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, store: Store<{}>) => {
            const props = {
                cid: 'public',
                options: {
                    relations: [
                        'location',
                        'location.address',
                        'quotations',
                        'quotations.owner',
                        'quotations.owner.company',
                        'quotations.documents',
                        'certificates',
                        'certificatesCustom',
                        'documents',
                    ],
                    scopes: ['public'],
                    filters: {
                        category: ['transformer'],
                        deadline: ['0-10'],
                    },
                    order: ['projectName:desc'],
                },
            };
            spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
            (<Subject<{}>>activatedRoute.queryParams).next({
                'filters[category]': 'transformer',
                'filters[deadline]': '0-10',
                order: 'projectName:desc',
            });
            fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(publicProjectsListLoad({...props}));
        },
    ));
});
```

Comment: I tried importing as root, but still get the same warnings. Is the `initialState` in `provideMockStore` is the initialState of `app` store only? I tried combining with `featureInitialState`, still same warnings

Comment: I've added an example. Perhaps, it may be useful.

Comment: What I see in my tests for store, I do not import `StoreModule.forRoot` at all, maybe that is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank You SatanTime. I finally found the issue. I had individual states for modules and app state didnt contain them all. So, when I was mocking with just app state, the test needed mock state of module as well which didnt exist in initial state i was passing to mock store.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. I had individual states for modules and app state didnt contain them all. So, when I was mocking with just app state, the test needed mock state of module as well which didnt exist in initial state I was passing to mock store.

As per Angular 8 docs, the examples showed, app store state should have state of all the modules, which was missing in my case.

Got it fixed through a band-aid solution, where, we created a fake initial state extending app and module states. And then, passing that fake initial state to the mock store.